# How to resign keyboard while click on outside using TouchesBegan and TouchesEnd of textField SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a `TextField` to get a user name in **SwiftUI framework**

I have done a code of implementing `TextField` in `SwiftUI`. and also I have implemented while the user clicks the return button on the keyboard. But I have to resign a keyboard while user tap on BackGround view *(
ContentView or non TextField View)*

Have to implement `Touches began and Touches End` tracking

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var name: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Good monring \(name)")
            TextField($name, placeholder: Text("Name...")) {
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but wouldn't a `tapAction` on the `VStack` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide keyboard when using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui)

Comment: here is a example for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56496669/1501847

Comment: @zero3nna above link is not flexibly working like touches began in UIKit

Comment: I tried this only. Its not working well