# SwiftUI Textfield Trigger Commit Manually iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui

The issue I have is that the **decimalFormatter** will not trigger and update the binding unless the **textField gets a commit event triggered**, i.e. return is tapped.

Thus, I'm looking for **how do you manually trigger the textfields commit event?**

The formatter code below will take any number and ensure it always has one decimal place (I.E -- 10.5) and also reverts the input back to the previous valid input if letter characters were inserted which is exactly what I want.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct StandardRegimen: View {
    @State private var totalDose = 6000.0

    private var decimalFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.isLenient = true
        f.numberStyle = .none
        f.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        f.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        f.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
        return f
    }()

    var body: some View{
       return
       VStack(alignment:.center,spacing:10){
            TextField("?", value:$totalDose, formatter: self.decimalFormatter, onCommit: {
               print("COMMITED!");
            }).font(.system(size: 25.0))
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
       }
    }
```

If you remove the modifier code `.keyboardType(.decimalPad)` and press the **return key** on the keyboard it will trigger the **COMMITED message and close the keyboard**

However, **if you leave the decimal pad modifier on** then there is no way to trigger the commit because the decimal pad does not have a return key.

I wrote an answer here on how to get the keyboard to go away by tapping in the open space area ([How to hide keyboard when using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui/59402180#59402180))

I have looked into other solutions using binding to a string and using the textfields `text` initializer parameter instead of value since this will work correctly with a bound value, **but this updates on every keystroke for some very wonky results** (I.E -- it's difficult for the user to type and edit mistakes) when I'm looking for it to run the formatter **only just after commit**, which I want to occur when the user taps to dismiss the keyboard **since I will not have the return key option on the decimal keypad.**

Any help is appreciated on solutions to this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same challenge. Joseph, did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: no luck so far to my knowledge, I can't use swiftUI until this is fixed unfortunately so been coding using interface builder for now.

Answer (score 6):

This may be a little late, but I have come up with a workaround for using other keyboard types with a `TextField`: I use the `onEditingChanged` event instead of the `onCommit` event and check the `Bool` value passed into the method. If the value is false, it replicates the behavior of the `onCommit` method. Here is your code but formatted to use my method:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct StandardRegimen: View {
    @State private var totalDose = 6000.0

    private var decimalFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.isLenient = true
        f.numberStyle = .none
        f.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        f.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        f.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
        return f
    }()

    var body: some View{
       VStack(alignment:.center,spacing:10){
            TextField("?", value:$totalDose, formatter: self.decimalFormatter, onEditingChanged: { edit in
                // Editing has finished
                if !edit {
                    print("COMMITED!");
                }
            }).font(.system(size: 25.0))
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
       }
    }
}
```

This solution should work for all keyboard types (I have only tested regular and num pad).

Comment: This works great! A shame onCommit with other Keyboards isn't flushed out (unless Apple wants really wants us to use fancy Pickers :-) )