# How to dismiss the number pad in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just started learning swift and decided to build a simple BMI calculator just to kind of learn everything. I think I've got everything working, but I can't hit the calculate button to test it because I can't get the keyboard to dismiss.

I've been looking all over the place trying to find a straight forward answer to this but can't seem to find one.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can add my code if need be.

Also, im using Xcode 11 and SwiftUI

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348988/swiftui-dismissing-keyboard-on-tapping-anywhere-in-the-view-issues-with-othe/60352449#60352449

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - dismissing keyboard on tapping anywhere in the view - issues with other interactive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348988/swiftui-dismissing-keyboard-on-tapping-anywhere-in-the-view-issues-with-othe)