# In SwiftUI is there a way to create a state variable that is bound to whether or not the view being defined is the first responder?

Tags: ios, swiftui, first-responder

I am trying to put an overlay on a text field when it is the active first responder in the current scene.

```
TextField("", text: valueProxy, onEditingChanged: { self.isEditing = $0 })
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).stroke(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: self.isEditing ? 1: 0))
```

This works well when all the fields on the form are text fields, but it stops working when a toggle control or some other field is tapped.

In those cases `onEditingChanged` does not appear to be called at all, so I could end up with potentially having multiple fields that look like they have focus.

NOTE:
The closest I got was to dismiss the keyboard upon tap occurring elsewhere, based on the question below

[How to hide keyboard when using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui/57639614#57639614)

But even that has limitations when certain views are configured to appear/disappear upon gestures other than onTap.

I think a safer approach would be to check for first responder status and bind any custom highlighting to that variable. Does anyone have a method that can expose if a view is indeed the first responder?

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things. the easiest way to dismiss keyboard upon tab is to use this library, https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager. theres an issue that talks about how to use it in swiftUI, https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1606.

As for finding the responder status, i use another library called Introspect, https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect. with it you can do this:

````
TextField("", text: valueProxy)
  .introspectTextField { textField in self.isEditing = textField.isFirstResponder }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).stroke(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: self.isEditing ? 1: 0))```
````