# How to fix a Picker navigation works only when I long press a link

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

When I use a `onTapGesture` at `Form` in `NavigationView`, navigation of `Picker` the inside doesn't work.

It works but only when I long-press a link like a `LongPressGesture`.

If I don't use `onTapGesture`, the navigation of `Picker` works, as usual, But in that case, I can not close a keyboard when I use `TextField` choosing `numberPad` as `keyboardType`...

How could I solve this problem?

---

Here is a code:

OnTapGestureTest.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnTapGestureTest: View{
    
    @State var inputNo:String = ""
    @State var selectNo:Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                TextField("InputNo", text: $inputNo)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                
                Picker(selection:$selectNo, label: Text("SelectNo")){
                    Text("0").tag(0)
                    Text("1").tag(1)
                    Text("2").tag(2)
                    Text("3").tag(3)
                    Text("4").tag(4)
                    Text("5").tag(5)
                    
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATED**

I tried to solve my question by referencing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010955/8700044).

*I want to close keyboard only on Tap outside (without handling drags) in iOS 13.0

SceneDelegate.swift

```
...
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
...
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: window, action:#selector(UIView.endEditing))
        tapGesture.requiresExclusiveTouchType = false
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGesture.delegate = self 
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
...
```

But it still doesn't work well... Do I need to do some more things? misunderstand the answer?

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 13.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the tap gesture globally, with the help of `UIWindow`:

```
extension UIApplication {
    
    func addTapGestureRecognizer() {
        guard let window = windows.first else { return }
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: window, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        tapGesture.requiresExclusiveTouchType = false
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        window.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}


extension UIApplication: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true 
    }
}
```

In your main: (The idea: as soon as your app launches, this tapGesture is added to the window)

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    
    ...
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            //Your initial view
                .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.addTapGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }
}
```

This is especially convenient since you don't have to take care of hiding the keyboard ever again inside your views and it's not blocking any of your controls.

### Note

This code is from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63942065/8700044)

Also, I saw iOS13 - for non SwiftUI Cycle, this would be the equivalent: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010955/8700044)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried to do a couple of solutions by referencing this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010955/8700044` like my updated question. Do I need to add some code in my struct `OnTapGestureTest.swift`?

Comment: Did you remove the tapGesture from the `Form`?

Comment: No I didn't change anything in the `Form`.

Comment: Otherwise, you could try to use my solution for SwiftUI Cycle. Just add the `onAppear` to your initial view inside your `SceneDelegate`. Should be the same. It's working fine for me.

Comment: You should get rid of the tapGesture inside your `OnTapGestureTest`.

Comment: I removed `tapGesture`, and then it works well, Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: Perfect! I am happy to help.