# SwiftUI Dismiss Keyboard from UITextField

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, resignfirstresponder, uiviewrepresentable

So for my own reasons, I need the full control that UITextField and its delegates would normally offer, but the screen it's being added to is written with SwiftUI. Needs a `.decimal` keyboard, so no Return Key.

I have only 2 issues remaining, 1 of which I hope to resolve here. Attempting to add a call to resign first responder and add it to a VStack on the page basically disables the UITextField, since I can't bring up the keyboard.

How can I dismiss this keyboard without adding an arbitrary extra button to the page?

Example Code:

```
Struct CustomTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    /// Insert init, updateView, binding variable, coordinator, etc
    func makeView() -> UITextField {
        var textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        /// Set up rest of textfield parameters such as Font, etc.
        return textField
    }
}

extension CustomTextView {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        /// UITextfield delegate implementations, extra reference to binding variable, etc
        /// Primarily textField.shouldChangeCharactersInRange
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextView($viewModel.parameter)
            /// Other views
        }
        .onTap {
            /// Attempting to add the generic call to UIApplication for resignFirstResponder here does not allow CustomTextView to ever hold it even when tapped in
        }
    }
}
```

I can't give all the code for privacy reasons, but this should be enough to establish my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide keyboard when using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a trick on my own with an epiphany overnight.

First, I would like to share to anyone else a very basic reason why inb4cookies solution wasn't quite adequate. While I had already tried adding a resignFirstResponder call like it to the `onTap` of the background stack, it was triggering the onTap for the `VStack` when I was clicking the field.

This is likely because I am using a `UITextField` as the back end for this component and not a SwiftUI `TextField`.

However, it was partially used in the final solution. I still applied it, but there is an extra step.

```
VStack {
            CustomTextView($viewModel.parameter)
            .onTap {/*Insert literally any compiling code here*/ }
            /// Other views
        }
        .onTap {
            self.hideKeyboard()
        }
```

You'll see that above, there is an extra `onTap`. I tested it with a `print` statement, but this will override the `onTap` for the `VStack` and prevent the keyboard from being dismissed right after it is brought up. Tapping anywhere else on the VStack still closes it, except for Buttons. But I can always add `hideKeyboard` to those buttons if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this by adding this Function to you view below.

```
    func hideKeyboard() {
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
}
```

Then with a ontapGesture you can make the keyboard go away.
For example you can use this on the background Stack of your whole view. If a user taps on the background the keyboard will dissapear.

```
.onTapGesture {
    self.hideKeyboard()
}
```

Comment: Right, I tried that. But then tapping on the UITextField triggers it to, so the keyboard never happens