# Tapping out of a keyboard through TextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently making an app that takes in three user inputs for a red, green, and blue color value between 0 and 255 through separate `TextField` views. Right now, the user can input the values fine but there is no way of tabbing out of the keyboards. I understand there are two main ways to go about this. The first is adding a return button to the keyboard and the second is exiting out through a tap gesture.

I am fairly new to SwiftUI and I keep seeing online that the best solution is to override the viewDidLoad function and set a tap gesture in there. I am honestly not sure what the `viewDidLoad` function is and I am still very confused after researching it. At the moment, I am also not very familiar with `UIViewController`s.

Is there an easier way to solve my issue or will I have to use a `UIViewController` and override the `viewDidLoad` function?
enter code here

```
VStack {
    TextField("255", text: $redC) { editing in
        isEditing = editing
        redV = (redC as NSString).doubleValue
    } onCommit: {
        redV = (redC as NSString).doubleValue
    }
    TextField("255", text: $greenC) { editing in
        isEditing = editing
        greenV = (greenC as NSString).doubleValue
    } onCommit: {
        greenV = (greenC as NSString).doubleValue
    }
    TextField("255", text: $blueC) { editing in
        isEditing = editing
        blueV = (blueC as NSString).doubleValue
    } onCommit: {
        blueV = (blueC as NSString).doubleValue
    }
}
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
.keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

Comment: My work is being done all in SwiftUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide keyboard when using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui)

Comment: It is definitely what I need but I am still getting an issue with sendAction where it is not in my scope

Comment: this could be useful: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield

Comment: sendAction is not used in all of the answers in the link I posted. Please read further — there are many answers with different solutions and many upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Use `onTapGesture` closure

First Create an extension in UIApplication like that,

```
extension UIApplication {    
    func resignFirstResponder() {
            sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
}
```

Add this in `VStack` like that,

```
 VStack {

      // contents

       }
        .onTapGesture {
               UIApplication.shared.resignFirstResponder()
        }
```

Comment: I tried something along these lines but I keep getting the issue where sendAction is not in my scope. Do I have to import anything other than SwiftUI?

Comment: Add `import UIKit`

Comment: I have, but I am still getting the issue

Comment: I have edited the answer. Try now