# TextField does not return on outside tap

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, textfield, resignfirstresponder

I'm a novice Swift and SwiftUI developer and I have a textfield embedded in a form. I'd like the textfield to return when the user taps anywhere outside of the textfield, and I'm struggling to make this happen. The following toy example illustrates the problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var selectedPickerChoice: String = ""
    
    enum FocusedField {
        case name, selectedPickerItem
    }
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    let pickerOptions = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("Name")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .autocapitalization(.words)
                        .focused($focusedField, equals: .name)
                }
                /*  .onTapGesture {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    } */
                
                Picker("Picker Choice", selection: $selectedPickerChoice) {
                    ForEach(pickerOptions, id: \.self) { option in
                             Text(option)
                    }
                }
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .selectedPickerItem)
            } // End of Form
         /* .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            } */
        } // End of NavigationView
    } // End of body view
} // End of ContentView
```

In this code example, you can see that I've attempted both .resignFirstResponder and the iOS 15 @FocusState as solutions. Note that the .resignFirstResponder WILL cause the textfield to resign if I use it as a modifier for the form and not the HStack or textfield itself, but when I do this, the picker no longer works.

I am looking to do this without resorting to storyboard and UITextField solutions, and have tried a variety of solutions, including those described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui) (using Xcode 13.2.1 and 13.2 beta 2) without success.

Any advice is deeply appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I tried a number of things, also some of the SO answers, nothing worked :(  –  the only unsatisfactory solution was to reduce the form height to a minimum and put some clear color underneath it that detects the taps and set focussedField to nil. But that's far from elegant or even practical.

Comment: Hi ChrisR - thank you so much for your time and effort! At least I know that I'm not alone in struggling with this. I'll keep your workaround in mind.