# SwiftUI: How to check for a UITextRangeView?

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I am using the auto keyboard dismiss SwiftUI code from [How to hide keyboard when using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui/60010955#60010955)

Under AnyGestureRecognizer, I'll like to cancel when the touch is still within the UITextView or if it is on a selected Text within a SwiftUI TextField (e.g. that user can drag to select a wider range of the text).

I've noticed that when I tap on the selected text (i.e. 'consequent' in the image below which is already selected), the touchesBegan function returns 'state = .began'. And touches.first?.view is returned as

```
▿ Optional<UIView>
  - some : <UITextRangeView: 0x104f0b750; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2832778a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x283c06440>>
```

I tried to check if add a if statement to check if touches.first?.view is a UITextRange but it returns nil.  **How can I check for a UITextRangeView?**. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue with selecting text with drag with the changes to the [AnyGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010955)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    if let touchedView = touches.first?.view, touchedView is UIControl {
        state = .cancelled

    } else if let touchedView = touches.first?.view as? UITextView, touchedView.isEditable {
        state = .cancelled

    } else {
        
        if var touchedView = touches.first?.view {
            while let superview = touchedView.superview {
                if let view = superview as? UITextView, view.isEditable {
                    state = .cancelled
                    return
                } else {
                    touchedView = superview
                }
            }
        }
        
        state = .began
    }
}
```