Dismiss keyboard and submit text in TextField when NavigationLink tapped
I have a List containing a TextField and a couple of NavigationLink items. When I tap into the TextField, the keyboard appears and I can enter a text. I would like to hide the keyboard and submit the text value when I click on anything other than the field.
var body: some View {
  List {
    Section("Input") {
      HStack {
        Text("Field 1")
        Spacer()
        TextField("Text 1", text: $text1)
          .focused($isFocusedField1)
      }
    }
    Section("Items") {
      ForEach(items) { item in
        NavigationLink(value: item) {
          ItemView(item: item)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The general way with onTapGesture and UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil) makes the NavigationLink's untapable.
When adding onChange(on: isFocusedField1) to the TextField, the focus is not changed when tapping on a NavigationLink.
How can I dismiss the keyboard and submit the value?

maybe this SO post with answers can help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui

You can’t with this setup. You can if you change the Link to a Button and append to the path
