# SwiftUI - Close Keyboard on Scroll

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a simple search list:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text:String = ""
    var items = 1...100
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                TextField("Search", text: $text)
                Section{
                    ForEach(items.filter({"\($0)".contains(text)}),id: \.self){(i) in
                       Text("option \(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]
How can I make the keyboard close when scrolling for more than 2 cells/few points?

Answer (score 29):

If you are using a `ScrollView` (probably also with a `List` but I haven't confirmed it), you could use the `UIScrollView` `appearance`, this will affect all ScrollViews though.

```
UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Comment: This is the best suggestion so far. Also works well with other views / components like a `Slider` on the same scroll view

Comment: This works for `List`, as I tested, and probably other scrollable views as well. I guess it is because `List` is a subclass of `ScrollView`

Comment: I found that if the Emoji keyboard is shown and you slide the emojis, this causes the keyboard to hide weirdly - any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Use this only when you dont have any TextEditor or text views that scrolls because those also gets affected by the this universal configuration

Answer (score 12):

As for now, since iOS 16 beta we have a new modifier `scrollDismissesKeyboard()` that allows to do exactly what you need.

In your example it should look like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var items = 1...100
    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("Search", text: $text)
            Section {
                ForEach(items.filter({"\($0)".contains(text)}), id: \.self) { (i) in
                    Text("option \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively) // <<-- Put this line
    }
}
```

The `scrollDismissesKeyboard()` modifier has a parameter that determine the dismiss rules. Here are the possible values:

- `.automatic`: Dismissing based on the context of the scroll.
- `.immediately`: The keyboard will be dismissed as soon as any scroll happens.
- `.interactively`: The keyboard will move/disappear inline with the user’s gesture.
- `.never`: The keyboard will never dismissed when user is scrolling.

Answer (score 11):

A thorough discussion on how to resign the keyboard with various answers can be found for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491386/how-to-hide-keyboard-when-using-swiftui).

One solution to resign the keyboard on a drag gesture in the list is using a method on UIApplication window as shown below. For easier handling I created an extension on UIApplication and view modifier for this extension and finally an extension to View:

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing(_ force: Bool) {
        self.windows
            .filter{$0.isKeyWindow}
            .first?
            .endEditing(force)
    }
}

struct ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture: ViewModifier {
    var gesture = DragGesture().onChanged{_ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.gesture(gesture)
    }
}

extension View {
    func resignKeyboardOnDragGesture() -> some View {
        return modifier(ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture())
    }
}
```

So the final modifier for resigning the keyboard is just one modifier that has to be placed on the list like this:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(...) {
        //...
    }
}
.resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
```

I have also implemented a pure swiftUI version of a search bar that might be interesting for you. You can find it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490963/how-to-display-a-search-bar-with-swiftui/58473985#58473985).

Comment: I don't know if this is still actively monitored but for iOS 15, I got a warning that says `'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead`. Would be helpful to add a code section for iOS 15.

Comment: One possibility to overcome the deprecation as of iOS 15 that I found [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682621) is to use 
        let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        let window = windowScene?.windows.first
        window?.endEditing(force)

Comment: But with my solution I had the issue, that pressing the back button on navigation views would require pressing it with a slight pan. It worked, but annoyed sometimes. Meanwhile I tested the above on-liner [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540763/swiftui-close-keyboard-on-scroll/64536489#64536489) from [vauxhaull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4691224/vauxhall) and it seems to work well, but not having this issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
Form {
    ...
}.gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { _ in
    UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { $0.endEditing(false) }
})
```

Comment: I find that this interferes with the swipe to delete unfortunately.

Comment: Also with the `Slider` component

Comment: Strangely, it only works horizontally for me.

Answer (score 5):

`@FocusState` wrapper along with `.focused()` `TextField` modifier can be useful.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var focusedSearchField: Bool
    @State var text:String = ""
    var items = 1...100
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                TextField("Search", text: $text)
                    .focused($focusedSearchField)
                Section{
                    ForEach(items.filter({"\($0)".contains(text)}),id: \.self){(i) in
                        Text("option \(i)")
                    }
                }
            } // to also allow swipes on items (theoretically)
            .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
                focusedSearchField = false
            }))
            .onTapGesture { // dissmis on tap as well
                focusedSearchField = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct EndEditingKeyboardOnDragGesture: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.highPriorityGesture (
            DragGesture().onChanged { _ in 
                UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
            }
        )
    }
}

extension View {
    func endEditingKeyboardOnDragGesture() -> some View {
        return modifier(EndEditingKeyboardOnDragGesture())
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it interferes with the swipe gesture.