# SwiftUI Emoji Keyboard hidden with ScrollView

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

When I try below code and show Emoji keyboard, keyboard will hide with Emoji keyboard horizontal scroll.

I applied "keyboardDismissMode" to make keyboard hide with scrollview
but I think "keyboardDimissMode" apples Emoji keyboard's ScrollView also.
so I would like to apply that only ScrollView in the ContentView.
Are there any solutions?

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        TextField("Text", text: $text)
    }
    .onAppear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    }
}
```

}

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTKKG.gif)

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently a bug in Apple's keyboard implementation. I ran into the same problem just now and filed a bug report. It also happened with `keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag`.

There is a workaround when you only want this keyboard dismiss behavior for `Lists`. In this case, you can simply use

```
UITableView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
–––––––––––
```

The reason this works is that Apple uses a `UICollectionView` for laying out their Emoji keyboard. Both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` inherit from `UIScrollView`, so when you set

```
UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
––––––––––––
```

it also affects the Emoji keyboard and the bug occurs. When only changing the `UITableView`'s appearance, it doesn't affect `UICollectionView` and thus the bug does not occur.

If you need this behavior with `LayzHGrid`, `LazyVGrid`, or `ScrollViews` in general, I'm afraid that there is no working solution currently (to my knowledge).

##### Reference

For further information, please also refer to this question:
[SwiftUI - Close Keyboard on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58540763/2062785)