# Create search bar for SwiftUI List for macOS - compiler unable to type-check expression in reasonable time

Tags: macos, search, core-data, filter, swiftui

I want to introduce a case (and maybe diacritic) insensitive search function into a "search bar" across the top of a SwiftUI List to dynamically filter the list, however...

> "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

*Using Core Data framework. Currently using Xcode 11.5, writing Swift 5.*

In iOS programming I have always used a `UISearchBar` with the `updateSearchResults(for:)` method to rebuild an `NSFetchedResultsController` with a compound `NSPredicate` - in the FRC I would check...

```
if
    searchController.isActive,
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text,
    searchText.count > 0 {

    // and build `NSCompoundPredicate` here, to subsequently add to the FRC fetch request.
}
```

I chose this method over filtering a mutable array copy of the data set as I understood that it was/is far more efficient.

But Apple's sample code in their SwiftUI Tutorial is much different, and uses this conditional if statement...

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
    @Binding var selectedLandmark: Landmark?
    @Binding var filter: FilterType

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedLandmark) {
            ForEach(userData.landmarks) { landmark in
                if (!self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite)
                    && (self.filter == .all
                        || self.filter.category == landmark.category
                        || (self.filter.category == .featured && landmark.isFeatured)) {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark).tag(landmark)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you've run through the tutorial and built this macOS app you'll know this works well.

So how to implement a search bar?

I read some blogs and SO Q&A.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738103/1883707) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56490963/1883707) "how to display a search bar with SwiftUI" had me thinking I could use `NSViewRepresentable`, but AppKit does not have the same (now) easy to use search tools as UIKit, so I'd be back to learning more AppKit.

The [answer with the most votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473985/1883707) to the same question is a really great solution but also involves a lot of code.

My current solution involved building on the existing Filter struct in the Apple SwiftUI tutorial:

To Apple's struct `Filter`...

1. add a new wrapped property `@Binding var searchText: String` to Apple's struct `Filter`;
2. add a `TextField()` and `Button` into an `HStack` and add that into a `VStack` with the existing controls;

To the SwiftUI `List`...

3. add a new wrapped property `@Binding var searchText: String` to my SwiftUI `List`;
4. rewrite the conditional if statement in the `List` to include a check for `searchText`.

...and the code...

```
struct Filter: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
    @Binding var filter: FilterType

    // 1. NEW PROPERTY
    @Binding var searchText: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // 2. NEW TEXTFIELD WITH CANCEL BUTTON
            HStack {
                TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                Button("Cancel", action: {
                    self.searchText = String()
                })
            }
            HStack {
                Picker(selection: $filter, label: EmptyView()) {
                    ForEach(FilterType.allCases) { choice in
                        Text(choice.name).tag(choice)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Toggle(isOn: $appData.showFavouritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favourites")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and...Version 1... with help from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330465/1883707)...

```
var body: some View {

    List(selection: $selectedItem) {

        ForEach(fetchedItem) { item in
            // 4. REWRITE IF STATEMENT
            if (!self.userData.showFavouritesOnly || item.isFavourite)
                && (self.searchText.count == 0
                 ...EITHER...
                    || (item.name?.contains(where: { $0.compare(self.searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame}) == true))
                 ...OR...
                    || (item.name?.contains(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare(self.searchText) == .orderedSame}) == true))
                && (self.filter == .all
                    || self.filter.name == item.category
                    || (self.filter.category == .featured && item.isFeatured)) {

                    ItemRow(item: item).tag(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and...Version 2...

```
var body: some View {

    List(selection: $selectedItem) {

        ForEach(fetchedItem) { item in
            // 4. REWRITE IF STATEMENT
            if (!self.userData.showFavouritesOnly || item.isFavourite)
                && (self.filter == .all
                    || self.filter.name == item.category
                    || (self.filter.category == .featured && item.isFeatured)) {

                if self.searchText.count == 0 {
                    if (item.name?.contains(where: { $0.compare(self.searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame}) == true) {

                        ItemRow(item: item).tag(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error message quoted at the start of this essay!

If I replace the more complicated `contains(where:_)` call with the following code, the "search" feature works perfectly, however is case sensitive.

```
(item.name?.contains(self.searchText) == true)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions please?

Comment: I've found a solution - it is not an answer to this question, but it does work - by implementing a generic `@FetchRequest` and using my old friend `NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [])`, with one of the predicates as `NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", predicateKey, predicateValue)`. The `[cd]` operator implements case and diacritic insensitive comparison.

Comment: have you tried `item.name?.lowercased().contains(self.searchText.lowercased())` You could also eagerly lowercase the searchText or even the name.

Also you can replace `== true` with `?? false`